# Running Virtual box in Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, virtualbox, rdp

I have installed a Virtual Box application inside the Windows 10 Azure VM.
Opened an 10gb OS image file using the virtual box application and immediately I am loosing the connection to the Azure VM

Azure VM - With 7 GB RAM
Virtual BOX - 6 GB

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 3):

Nested virtualization is only available on certain VM sizes in Azure.  You can view the regional availability of **Dv3** or **Ev3** series virtual machines [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/regions/services/).  I have only tested this with Hyper-V, I don't know if Virtualbox will work even with nested virt.  I will test and update my answer when I have more time.

Comment: Also want to know

Comment: I have tried a few times without any luck.  Furthest I got was getting VBox installed but when I go to boot a VM the host blue-screens.  I have not had much time that last few weeks to troubleshoot further, I am working a deal that is consuming most of my time.